# insert headings in word before every point through vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

have a document say as follows:

## Heading Short Intro

1. i have a account on stack overflow 
   1.1 heya
   1.2 hi
2. I use it to post questions
3. I use it to answer questions

I want to convert this into :

## Heading Short Intro - 1

1. i have a account on stack overflow
   1.1 heya
   1.2 hi

## Heading Short Intro - 2

2. I use it to post questions

## Heading Short Intro - 3

3. I use it to answer questions

I want to know how can i iterate over the numbered list collection to achieve this though macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate like this:

```
Sub iterateNumberedList()
   Dim oList As Paragraph

   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst ' go to beginning of doc

   ' for each paragraph
   For Each oList In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

      ' is it a numbered list of level 1 ?
      If oList.Range.ListFormat.ListType = 4 And oList.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1 Then

         ' move one line above list item
         Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

         ' insert heading text
         Selection.Range.Text = "Heading " & vbCr

         ' format heading text with style 'Heading 1'
         Selection.Range.Style = "Heading 1"

         ' move down two paragraphs
         Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

This code is just here to give you an idea of what to do. It is not meant to be the final solution to your problem.

Comment: Thnaks. that makes sense ! but i am unable to use selection object inside the loop. The position of the selection doesnt change as the loop progresses . I am wrting Selection.TypeText (" heya ") inside the if block, but the text keeps getting inserted at the 1st place my cursor was.Sorry for the silly question but I am new to vba.

Comment: i am unable to get the root cause of this behaviour. Can you shed some light pls

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I got an idea of the selection object from your answer, i assumed it to change with the loop by default at the start. You saved me great time :D